# Hiding the ticks on the X axis of Shield UI Chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

Is there a way to hide the ticks on the X axis? I am using a line type Shield UI chart. But I don't see any property that looks like the one I need:

```
axisX: {     
   ticksEnabled: false
}
```

or

```
axisX: {     
   ticksVisible: false
}
```

or anything like that. Since so is there another way to hide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an explicit value used for enabling the ticks. However since you are looking for a visible effect, I could suggest the following code:

```
axisX:{
  categoricalValues: ['2009','2010','2011'],
  ticksHeight: 11,
  ticksWidth: 0
},
```

As you can see you can set the ticks Width (or Height) to 0 in order to make them disappear.